# How to add a custom button which executes a custom function in vtiger CRM?

Tags: php, vtiger

I have a custom module which I made using a module builder, but it doesn't do exactly what I want.

I want to add a custom button next to:

[image: Button]

The button should look like this:

[image: New button]

What I want the `Refresh status` button to do is to execute a custom function within vtiger CRM.

The code of my module does not contain a `Add Docusign document` button, so I can not hardcode it into the script.

There are no results on Google which I could find that helped me with this, so if somebody can help me with how to do this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change \layouts\vlayout\modules\VtigerCrm\ListViewHeader.tpl

```
{if $MODULE eq 'Your_Module'}
    <span class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn refreshStatus" type="submit">Refresh Status</button>
    </span> 
{/if}
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks, only now I need the button to execute a custom workflow, is that also possible?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Why custom button? what will be expected output?

Comment: The expected output is that a specific script executes from the workflow map.